# JavaScript - object's functions referencing its fields

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Here is a (very) simplified version of my code:

```
    function Ctor() {
        this.i = 0;

        this.increment = function() { this.i++; },
        this.decrement = function() { this.i--; },

        this.display = function() { alert(this.i); }
    };
```

The problem is, when the code is run, under some circumstances `this` now points to something else.  I do more or less understand that `this` changes context from one function to another, but I though my increment function (and the others) would, by the magic of closures, "remember" what this is supposed to be.

I tried just eliminating this altogether, and simply referencing i in the functions.  That failed also.

What should these functions look like?

Answer (score 3):

You can not rely on what's in `this` in JavaScript. [More on this topic](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/05/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx).

I see you probably want to introduce private attributes like in OOP languages. John Resig [described this issue very well](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/).

```
function Field(val){
    var value = val;

    this.getValue = function(){
        return value;
    };

    this.setValue = function(val){
        value = val;
    };
}

var field = new Field("test");
field.value
// => undefined
field.setValue("test2")
field.getValue()
// => "test2"
```

JavaScript works a lot differently than conventional languages like Java, C++ or PHP. But you can get used to it :)

Comment: I'm slowly but surely getting used to it.  It's truly a beautiful language once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I tend to stay away from this type of approach. I consider myself a JavaScript purist, and while JavaScript does have the ability to create private variables, etc, it does so at the cost of performance and memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

In the instances where `this` changes, you can do this:

```
function() { obj.display(); }
```

Example:

```
var obj = new Ctor();

function foo(fn) {
    fn();
}

foo(function() {
    obj.display();
});
```

An alternative is to modify foo() to accept the context to execute the function with, like this:

```
function foo(fn, context) {
    fn.call(context);
}
```