# Can I use alert box in return statement?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var name = document.getElementById('myname').value;
  var phone = document.getElementById('myphone').value;
  var country = document.getElementById('mycountry').value;
  var mail = document.getElementById('mymail').value;
  return alert(name + " , " + phone + " , " + country + " , " + mail);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Name<input type="text" id="myname"><br> Phone
  <input type="text" id="myphone"><br> Country <input type="text" id="mycontry"><br> Mail
  <input type="text" id="mymail"><br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</div>
```

If yes, why don't I get expected result? Can anyone please see my code and correct me?

Comment: `alert` is a browser's way to notify user of something. It does not return anything

Comment: Please explain more of what you are trying to do, and perhaps more of your code and we might be able to help. As a guess, try to `return alert(name + " , " + phone + " , " + country + " , " + mail);`, then you could run `alert(myFunction());`

Comment: `alert()` does not return anything. I guess you could say that it returns `undefined`

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually I have to read user registrations details and show them in alert box.

Comment: @user10493493 check my updated answer

Comment: Misspelling for mycountry I’d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your working code. You were selecting the wrong id:

change `<input type="text" id="mycontry" /`> to ***`id="mycountry"`***

```js
function myFunction() {
  var name = document.getElementById('myname').value;
  var phone = document.getElementById('myphone').value;
  var country = document.getElementById('mycountry').value;
  var mail = document.getElementById('mymail').value;
  
  //var phone = document.getElementById('myphone').value;
  //var country = document.getElementById('mycountry').value;
  //var mail = document.getElementById('mymail').value;
  return alert(name + " , " + phone + " , " + country + " , " + mail);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Name <input type="text" id="myname" ><br>
  Phone <input type="text" id="myphone" ><br> 
  Country <input type="text" id="mycountry"><br> 
  Mail <input type="text" id="mymail" value=""><br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use, you can use return with `alert()` function. But, you cannot get any field's value from `alert()`. If you want to get fields value from `myFunction()`. You have to create objects.
e.g.

```
//create constructor

function myFunction(myname, myphone, mycountry, mymail) {
    this.name = myname;
    this.phone = myphone;
    this.country = mycountry;
    this.mail = mymail;
}

//create object

var obj = new myFunction("testName", "testPhone", "testCountry", "testMail");

window.onload = alert(obj.name + " , " + obj.phone + " , " + obj.country + " , " + obj.mail);
```

About [JavaScript - object's functions referencing its fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354177/javascript-objects-functions-referencing-its-fields)

Comment: It is not working. Actually I have to do this :-Read user registration details and show them in an alert box.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return anything since you're not using return value anywhere. You can just alert:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var name = document.getElementById('myname').value;
  var phone = document.getElementById('myphone').value;
  var country = document.getElementById('mycountry').value;
  var mail = document.getElementById('mymail').value;
  alert(name + " , " + phone + " , " + country + " , " + mail);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Name
  <input type="text" id="myname"><br> 
  Phone
  <input type="text" id="myphone"><br> 
  Country 
  <input type="text" id="mycountry"><br> 
  Mail
  <input type="text" id="mymail"><br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</div>
```

Notice that your actual problem was with country field: (your current code throws an error sating cannot read property value of null since the selected id is wrong)

```
  <input type="text" id="mycountry">
  <!-- was missing u in here ^^ -->
```